# Strikethrough in chat uses obsolete HTML strike element

Tags: support, chat, design, markdown

So... in chat, when we use the strike-through text like <s>this</s> with `---this---`, it is wrapped in the [`strike`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/strike) tags which are now obsolete. This is extremely irritating! Why not use [`s`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/s) or [`del`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/del)? (I would prefer the former).

[Example: [image]](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/17?m=20055812#20055812)

Comment: It should be `<del>`, not `<s>`. On the link you just posted: `However, <s> is not appropriate when indicating document edits; for that, use the <del> and <ins> elements, as appropriate.`

Comment: What is irritating about it? It hardly affects anything except to these that look at the source code. Besides, nobody knows, in a communicable way, what `s` and `del` really mean in HTML5.

Comment: @FlorianMargaine `<del>` seems appropriate for messages that were deleted (or edited to remove content), where `<s>` seems semantically correct for text that was struck-through from the beginning. Regardless, either is far better than the deprecated `<strike>`.

Comment: @FlorianMargaine It's not possible to determine that context in a chat message, therefore it's more appropriate to use the more generic `<s>` element.

Comment: How about `<del>` if that part of message was edited, and `<s>` if not? <s>I am sure SE is ready to take the hassle...</s>

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela I, among many, know in a communicable way, what `s` and `del` really mean in HTML5.

Comment: I'm going off to surround all images in all of my previous answers and questions with `<kbd>` tags.  Ta!

Comment: @AwalGarg, they have exactly the same effect as `strike`. In fact, `s` is just an old synonym for `strike`. Their verbal descriptions in HTML5 are vague and obscure (what does it mean to be “no longer relevant”?), and there are no objective criteria for deciding whether some struck-out text should be marked with one of them or another. And it would be idle “semantics”, since the choice between has no effects.

Comment: @Won't Ugh, you're going to be one of *those* people. See you on the dark sid... oh wait...

Comment: There are people who <s>take obscene pleasure</s> enjoy [writing under deletion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sous_rature). `<del>`, being a semantic markup may change how that is rendered when the physical markup style may be the correct one. It does not [represent a document change](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/text.html#h-9.4) history.

Comment: ...why remove the 'kthnxbye'? How much bandwidth could that little phrase possibly cost? @InfiniteRecursion

Comment: If two editors ( @hichris and I) removed it, then it's fairly evident that bandwidth isn't the concern in this case. **kthnxbye** is noise, and therefore it has been edited out.

Comment: noise is gooood